# OpenLayers3 ImageLayer blurs on zoom

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using an OpenLayers 3 map with a simgle static image displayed as an ImageLayer like the sample below:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/examples/static-image.html
On zooming in, the image gets blurred, is there any way to remove the blurring and get a sharp pixelated image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with a static image unless it is way bigger than all the resolutions you want to use on the map.

If you're looking for deep zooming into images, you may want to use Zoomify to create a tile pyramid for your image. See the Zoomify example for how this will look in the browser: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/zoomify.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up creating a tile pyramid.